# Linear system of ODE with simple non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve

$\begin{pmatrix}x'(t)\\y'(t)\end{pmatrix}= w \begin{pmatrix} 0&-e^{i\omega t} \\e^{-i\omega t} & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}$

where $\omega$ and $w$ are real constants.

Thanks.

Comment: am i high, or did you just take the derivative of a vector whAt

Comment: See edit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you so much.

Comment: @Saketh: There's nothing wrong with taking the derivative of a vector valued function.  The changed notation makes it more explicit, but there's nothing wrong in principle using the notation $v'$ if $v$ is a vector valued function of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The scalar equations are:

$$x'=-w\exp(-i\omega t)y(t)$$
$$y'=w\exp(-i\omega t) x(t).$$

Devide $dy/dt$ by $dx/dt$ to get

$$dy/dx=x/y.$$

This equation is separable. Can you complete it from here?

Answer (score 0):

2d take, sorry for the first one)
$$x'=-we^{-i\omega{t}}y$$
$$y'=we^{-i\omega{t}}x$$
Differentiate the first equation once
$$x''=i\omega{w}e^{-i\omega{t}}y-we^{-i\omega{t}}y'=-i\omega{x'}-w^{2}e^{2i\omega{t}}x$$
i.e.
$$x''+i\omega{x}'+w^{2}e^{-2i\omega{t}}x=0$$
Let $z=e^{-i\omega{t}}$
$$\frac{d}{dt}=-i\omega{z}\frac{d}{dz}$$
$$\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}=-\omega^{2}{z^{2}}\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}-\omega^{2}z\frac{d}{dz}$$
The resulting equation is
$$-\omega^{2}z^{2}x''-\omega^{2}{z}x'+\omega{2}zx'+w^{2}z^{2}x=0$$
$$x''-\frac{w^{2}}{\omega^{2}}x=0$$
$$x=c_{1}\cosh((w/\omega){z})+c_{2}\sinh((w/\omega){z})$$
Then it's trivial to find $y$